# Where to describe a State API variable?

Tags: 8, configuration

We can describe the configuration variables in the *.schema.yml files but there is a place to describe the State API variables?

I searched in the Core for some State variables and I don't find a description of them. And I searched in the State API docs without luck.

For the moment I add a comment explaining the variable where I set the value but maybe this is not the best approach for it.

Comment: as per https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/state-api/overview -
not really but if it is mission critical perhaps good old fashion hook_install 
or could make a config/optional/mymodule.state.yml then in hook_install phrase the file and set the state ?  if not perhaps change to use configfactory

Comment: This really just comes down to documentation. I generally put such documentation in either a README, or in the comments for the .module file.